# css 3D transition image

Tags: css, 3d, background-image

I am trying to create a 2 sided 3D link, I have the flip working and have one side red and one side blue, but I want to put images on either side not just colours. When using the "background-image" value in my css no image appears, could someone help please.

Here is my code:

```
   .flip3D > .front{
   position:absolute;
   -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
   background:#e51c1c; width:246.5px; height:164px; border-radius: 0px;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
 }  

   .flip3D > .back{
   position:absolute;
   -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
   background:#428bca; width:246.5px; height:164px; border-radius: 0px;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
 }
```

Comment: Please provide the jsfiddle that doesn't work

Comment: I think this is it!, Thanks!.

http://jsfiddle.net/c0qxs827/

Comment: [Works fine for me with images](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/c0qxs827/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you apply an image to a background it seems to work just fine.

```
 .flip3D > .front{
   position:absolute;
   -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
   background: url(...) no-repeat; width:246.5px; height:164px; border-radius: 0px;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
 }  

 .flip3D > .back{
   position:absolute;
   -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
   background: url(...) no-repeat; width:246.5px; height:164px; border-radius: 0px;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
 }
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/c0qxs827/2/